# Ranking, rating things based on a set of metrics

Tags: r, ranking, rating

I need to rank a set of things belonging to different kind (models) based on a list of performance metrics.

For thing of each model, I have the aggregated value ( mean) of let's say 4 metrics and each metric of the same importance (weight).

So I have the aggregated results for each model for each metric over many experiments like in the below table.

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| model  |  metric1  |  metric2  |  metric3  |  metric4  |  metric5 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| A      |      0.14 |      0.10 |    18.9   |     0.78  |    -92.1 |
| B      |     0.02  |     0.01  |    17.6   |     0.52  |    -94.7 |
| C      |     0.00  |     0.01  |     10.1  |     1.28  |    -94.2 |
| D      |      0.03 |     0.02  |     19.2  |      0.64 |    -95.1 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I need to use this to rank the models - A to D.
All metrics are equally important.
For all metrics, higher the value, the better the rank.
The ranking should capture the relative differences for each metric - meaning, for a metric, a model should be heavily rewarded or penalized depending on the direction.

One approach I was thinking was to use z-score standardization - for each metric compute the z-scores across models via standardization ( `(x- mean) / std_dev`) - subsequently take linear average of the z-score to come up with final score so as to rank the things.

Why would it work or not work ? Are there alternate and/or better approaches.

Comment: Is higher better for each metric or is lower better for each metric? Do you have a theoretical range of each metric score or standard to judge the meaning of the score? And does it make sense to mathematically treat each metric as equal to rank the model?

Comment: @AdamQuek -> higher the better for each metric. The z-score is a standard normal distribution. Yes, each metric do have the same importance - all metrics equally important.

Comment: You sound a little inconsistent: if all metrics are equally important, then why are you changing them by computing z-scores?  Since they appear to have (quite) different standard deviations, that appears to change their relative importance greatly.

Comment: I was thinking that by changing them to z-scores it would be able to represent the relative difference is standard deviation accurately.